# Webpage scaling done with CSS is causing distortion

Tags: html, css

With the code below (which someone graciously helped me with because I'm a newbie at `CSS`!), the image and links become distorted as I shrink the width of the browser window.

If I shrink the height of the browser window, scroll bars appear once it gets down below the width of the image (which is what I want). So shrinking the **height** works fine, but shrinking the **width** causes distortion. I want the links and image to always remain in the middle, but once the browser window becomes to small to contain it, I'd like the scroll bars to come into play.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here's the code...

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
    }
    body {
      margin: auto;
    }
    nav {
      counter-reset: links;
      display: flex;
      padding: 0 1em;
    }
    img {
      margin: 1em;
    }
    ul {
      padding: 0;
      margin: auto;
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    .a_font {
      font-size: 25px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="a_font" href="">My Link Here</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="a_font" href="">My Link Here</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="a_font" href="">My Link Here</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="a_font" href="">My Link Here</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="a_font" href="">My Link Here</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <img src="myimage.png" width="250" height="250" />
    <ul>
      <li><a class="a_font" href="">My Link Here</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="a_font" href="">My Link Here</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="a_font" href="">My Link Here</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="a_font" href="">My Link Here</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="a_font" href="">My Link Here</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use Javascript to detect the screen width and remove the scaling CSS, scroll bars will be placed automatically by the browser

Answer (score 0):

Without using `JavaScript`:

```
body {
    margin:auto;
    min-width: 600px; //or some other value
    overflow: scroll;
}
```